# I have a question of understanding in ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I have a question of understanding. Which is the better option in terms of safety and performance?

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ProfitTarget> chartTraderTP;

if (chartTraderTP.ContainsKey(orderId))
{
    //Store values for later use in Mouse Events
    chartTraderTP[orderId].OrderLabelRectText = rectTextOrderLabelTP;
    //We can draw the Rectangle based on the TextLayout used above
    if (!chartTraderTP[orderId].IsMovingOrder
        && (ChartTraderDisplayStyle == ChartTraderDisplayStyle.Own
            || ChartTraderDisplayStyle == ChartTraderDisplayStyle.Both))
    {
        RenderTarget.FillRectangle(rectTextOrderLabelTP, tpAreaBrushDx);
        RenderTarget.DrawRectangle(rectTextOrderLabelTP, tpOutlineBrushDx,
            LabelOutlineWidthTP);
        RenderTarget.DrawTextLayout(vectText, tpTextLayout, tpTextBrushDx,
            SharpDX.Direct2D1.DrawTextOptions.NoSnap);
    }
}
```

or

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ProfitTarget> chartTraderTP;
//Store values for later use in Mouse Events
if (chartTraderTP.ContainsKey(orderId))
{
    chartTraderTP[orderId].OrderLabelRectText = rectTextOrderLabelTP;
}
//We can draw the Rectangle based on the TextLayout used above
if (chartTraderTP.ContainsKey(orderId) && !chartTraderTP[orderId].IsMovingOrder
    && (ChartTraderDisplayStyle == ChartTraderDisplayStyle.Own
        || ChartTraderDisplayStyle == ChartTraderDisplayStyle.Both))
{
    RenderTarget.FillRectangle(rectTextOrderLabelTP, tpAreaBrushDx);
    RenderTarget.DrawRectangle(rectTextOrderLabelTP, tpOutlineBrushDx,
        LabelOutlineWidthTP);
    RenderTarget.DrawTextLayout(vectText, tpTextLayout, tpTextBrushDx,
        SharpDX.Direct2D1.DrawTextOptions.NoSnap);
}
```

The code is executed very often, and I would like to make the access as fast as possible but still threadsafe.

Comment: I would advise to use `var found = chartTraderTp.TryGetValue(orderId, out var profitTarget);` and if it's found work with the instance you retrieved.

Comment: @Knoop That assumes no other threads are editing the objects in the collection, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Servy that's true, but then you just need to lock the object you retrieved instead of the entire `Dictionary`. It's hard to say anything specific without more information about what different threads are doing.

Comment: @Knoop But now you're taking out multiple different locks, which increases complexity quite a bit.  It may be needed, it may not be, but saying they can just use `TryGetValue` and be done is pretty unlikely to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Neither are safe, as you're performing multiple operations while assuming the collection isn't changing between operations, which is not a safe assumption.

Since you want to use a number of different operations and need entire section to be logically atomic, just use a regular `Dictionary` and lock around the access to it.

Comment: `Dictionary`, a `lock`, combined with a single `TryGetValue` should be performant enough.

Comment: you mean lock like below? sorry i am a newbie ;-)

Comment: @Sidlercom You probably want to use the `lock` keyword, yes.  What you lock on and what goes in it will depend on more than what you've shown.

Answer (score -3):

```
   lock (chartTraderTP)
            {
                //Store values for later use in Mouse Events
                chartTraderTP[orderId].OrderLabelRectText = rectTextOrderLabelTP;
                //We can draw the Rectangle based on the TextLayout used above
                if (!chartTraderTP[orderId].IsMovingOrder && (ChartTraderDisplayStyle == ChartTraderDisplayStyle.Own || ChartTraderDisplayStyle == ChartTraderDisplayStyle.Both))
                {
                    RenderTarget.FillRectangle(rectTextOrderLabelTP, tpAreaBrushDx);
                    RenderTarget.DrawRectangle(rectTextOrderLabelTP, tpOutlineBrushDx, LabelOutlineWidthTP);
                    RenderTarget.DrawTextLayout(vectText, tpTextLayout, tpTextBrushDx, SharpDX.Direct2D1.DrawTextOptions.NoSnap);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Using lock on a `ConcurrentDictionary<T>` negates all its advantages, while preserving its disadvantages (awkward API, overhead). If you have to `lock`, you'd better do it on a normal `Dictionary<T>` instead.